# How to scroll listview smoothly to a certain row before SDK 8

Tags: android, listview, scroll, smoothing

I want to programmatically scroll a row to the top of listview,
I tried the setSelection method, but no scroll animation
how to? please.

Comment: Minilin, could you explain your solution? I really need this in my project. I tried with many methods, even passing motion events manually but it didn't work..

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried this myself, but would simulating touch events work for this?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html

Comment: Sometimes that's what it takes. ;)  If my suggestion helped, I'd greatly appreciate it if you would mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've searched and searched myself, and I do not believe there is any way to do this before API Level 8. If anyone suggests the View.scrollTo() or View.scrollBy() methods they will not work. Those move the entire View, not the content of the list.